# How to show table row data as a column?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have faced problem in selection data from database.

**Main table:**

```
TYPE          DATE

APPLE      2013-10-02 
BANANA     2013-2-4 
KIWI       2014-10-2
```

**I want to show**

```
APPLE                 BANANA                KIWI
2013-10-02           2013-2-4             2014-10-2
```

How can i do this ?

Answer (score 0):

In Excel this function is called Transpose.

You have one good example and working code here:
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/47902/how-to-transpose-convert-rows-as-columns-in-mysql

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT CASE WHEN Type = 'APPLE' Then Date End APPLE,
       CASE WHEN Type = 'BANANA' Then Date End BANANA,
       CASE WHEN Type = 'KIWI' Then Date End KIWI,
From Table1
```